# Find values in registry subkeys and delete them

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a simple script in PowerShell (trying to keep it to one line) that will:

- Recursively list all the subkeys in a registry key
- Find one that has a specific value
- Delete a different value of the subkey found in the previous step

This is my code so far:

```
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\KeyToQuery" -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.ValueA -eq "True"}
```

Beneath "KeyToQuery" is several subkeys of random names that contain identical values.

The first part of this works, but the Where-Object statement never evaluates to true. I also tried -match and -like to no avail.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\KeyToQuery" -Recurse |
ForEach-Object { Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath } |
Where-Object {$_.ValueA -eq "True"}
```

Comment: Didn't realise I needed to use the ForEach-Object cmdlet. Thanks!